# How do i reduce my apk size?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been using adt bundle from 2013, and the size of a 'hello world' apk is around **250kb** in contrast with **800kb** (in the new eclipse from 2014) which is almost 3 times. This is a dramatic difference. The question is, what is the new eclipse (2014) adding to my projects? how did the apk size rise so sharply? also after adding new google play services (rev 29), the apk size hits **3mb**.

i have been working with projects exported using net beans, and the apk size is normally around 10kb. (i am not sure about the IDE, but [this is](http://www.guidingtech.com/assets/postimages/2012/06/apkedit.exe.png) what the apk icons look like.)

Comment: It's hard to tell, without knowing anything about your project. I can only guess what could be happened. You are using the new support library, which has necessarily grown in size, to hold all the new features. Maybe, you are also using the new styles. Which add more stuff (didn't want to use the term "material").

Comment: new eclipse, 2014? Welcome to 2016!

Comment: `the new eclipse (2014)` what year is this again?

Comment: @Henry and njk2 the final ADT bundle built was 2014/07/02, the release date is same as the name.

Comment: I am using and talking about ADT bundle in this question. i did not download the standalone individual builds due to some reason